# How to use MediaElement.NaturalDuration to set MediaTimeline.Duration in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, mediaelement, duration

My MVVM program is a media player and uses the Media Element's Natural Duration property to set the Media Timeline's duration. Before I implemented MVVM design pattern, I could simply put

```
    MyMediaTimeline.Duration = MyMediaElement.NaturalDuration;
```

in the code-behind. I am new to using MVVM but I believe this is not the correct way to perform this action according to the MVVM design pattern. I believe that MediaElement.NaturalDuration is not a dependency property so it cannot be bound to directly. Do I need to make it a dependency property somehow? Would this be coded in the ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we need to implement functionality like this that relates to UI controls using MVVM, we have a few options. One is to implement some kind of service or manager class that can implement this functionality for us and another is to use `Attached Properties`. Out of *these* two options, I believe this second option to be more suitable for this problem.

However, there is absolutely nothing wrong with adding event handlers into the code behind of your view, even when using MVVM. I *keep* seeing new users panicking over what to do rather than use the code behind when using MVVM. This is a common misconception about MVVM.

If you really know how to use `Attached Properties` properly, then I would advise that you use one (or more) of those to solve your problem, otherwise I would happily advise you to use the code behind. Note that if your view models are correctly data bound to your views, then you can access your view model from the code behind like this:

```
TypeOfViewModel viewModel = (TypeOfViewModel)DataContext;
```

Comment: Its good to know I can use event handlers in the code behind. Thank you for the suggestions. I will go ahead and try to implement the attached properties. Thank you. @Sheridan